# Given a url www.site.com/test, route to www.site.com/#testinner with javascript, without hardcoding base url

Tags: javascript

Given a url `www.site.com/test`, how can I route to `www.site.com/#testinner` with javascript, without hardcoding base url?  By route - I mean including a refresh / page load.

This gives me `settings#lol`:

```
var desiredBase = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";
var path = '#lol';
window.location.href = desiredBase + path;
location.reload();
```

Comment: Do you man something like `window.location.href= window.location.origin +'/' + path`?

Comment: @BenjiLees that doesn't reload.

Comment: Really? where are you running the script? I just put that in my browser console and it worked fine. You should not have to use the reload method, that is designed to reload the current page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just search for `/test` at the end of the and replace it with `/#testinner`. Here's an example:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/\/test$/, "/#testinner");
```

Here's a snippet showing the basic idea. You can see that it automatically navigates to the `#testinner` bookmark without having to refresh the page. Of course, the snippet's URL doesn't end in `/test` so I had to modify what it's replacing, and `/#testinner` doesn't exist inside the snippet so I had to modify that a bit as well. But the concept is the same. I've also included the current URL in the markup, since you can't see that very easily within the snippet.

```js
document.getElementById("currUrl").innerText = location.href;

location.href = location.href.replace(/\/js$/, "/js#testinner");

document.getElementById("currUrl").innerText = location.href;
```

```css
.vert-spacer {
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vert-spacer"></div>
<div id="testinner">Test Bookmark</div>
Current URL: <span id="currUrl"></span>
```

Comment: It works fine without a refresh in Chrome 57. Really, it should work fine in all browsers, as it's part of the HTML spec that updating the location is supposed to trigger a navigation to the specified URL.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a snippet that shows it working as expected